# How to keep hyphen in output string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have following requirement.

**Input**    ----------:     `z-edu-l1-^threat -emergency mk pl.jpg`

**Required** ----:   `z-edu-l1-_threat_-emergency_mk_pl.jpg`

I use following

```
$input = 'z-edu-l1-^threat -emergency mk pl.jpg';

echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\W(?![^.-]*$)/', '_', trim($input)));
```

I get following output

```
z_edu_l1__threat__emergency_mk_pl.jpg
```

I do not want to replace the - symbol with underscore. How do I keep hyphen in output string with preg_replace?

Comment: should special characters also be removed?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes special characters should also be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace `\W` with its negated character class equivalent `[^\w]` and negate the symbols you need to preserve:

```
[^\w.-]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Caxmx7/1)

The `[^\w.-]` matches any char that is not a letter/digit, `_`, `.` and `-`.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5QtiD6):

```
$input = 'z-edu-l1-^threat -emergency mk pl.jpg';
echo strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\w.-]/', '_', trim($input)));
// => z-edu-l1-_threat_-emergency_mk_pl.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "z-edu-l1-^threat -emergency mk pl.jpg";
$output = str_replace(["^", " "], "_", $input);
echo $output;
//output
//z-edu-l1-_threat_-emergency_mk_pl.jpg
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

[^something] will find a match except {something}
\w -> alphabets
[^\w.-] will find anything except alpha, period and hyphen and replace it with underscore.

```
$input = 'z-edu-l1-^threat -emergency mk pl.jpg';

echo strtolower(preg_replace('([^\w.-])', '_', trim($input)));
```

See a live [demo here](http://main.xfiddle.com/6c019a87/test.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - an explanation of your Regular Expression, and how it solves the OP's question would be helpful

Comment: In which way is this different from @WiktorStribiżew 's answer?

Comment: @Toto I didn't saw his answer. While i choose to answer and testing it on phpfiddle, no answers were received. After posting only I saw the answer.